# Getting error in HttpResponse response = new client.execute(post); where execute shows error

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

i am making android json listview app.

Getting error in `HttpResponse response = new client.execute(post);`

`where` execute shows error. it is not able to import jar.

i added httpclient-4.5.1.jar  in my project also.

```
 try {
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
               HttpResponse response = new client.execute(post);
                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if( status==200 ) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);

                    JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("actors");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        Actors actor = new Actors();

                        JSONObject jRealObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        actor.setName(jRealObject.getString("name"));
                        actor.setDescription(jRealObject.getString("description"));
                        actor.setDob(jRealObject.getString("dob"));
                        actor.setCountry(jRealObject.getString("country"));
                        actor.setHeight(jRealObject.getString("height"));
                        actor.setSpouse(jRealObject.getString("spouse"));
                        actor.setChildren(jRealObject.getString("children"));
                        actor.setImage(jRealObject.getString("image"));

                        actorsList.add(actor);
                    }

                }
               } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return false;
        }
```

Comment: Post your error... anyway, `HttpClient, HttpPost, HttpResponse` it's deprecated...

Answer (score 1):

the `new` keyword is used to instantiate an object, and requires as single argument, the name  of the constructor of the class you want to instantiate, not an instance. In your case

changing

```
HttpResponse response = new client.execute(post);
```

with

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

will fix the compile time error. `client`, is an instance of `DefaultHttpClient`

Comment: I'm not the user who ask that question but... anyway, can you explain me what do you mean?

Comment: @Aspicas The new operator requires a single, postfix argument: a call to a constructor. The name of the constructor provides the name of the class to instantiate.